# table sequence_order_1 does not exist

Tags: magento2.4

I am using magento 2.4 while MSI  is enabled. when check out , an exception occurred,

main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.sequence_order_1' doesn't exist,

I check the magento db using phpMyAdmin and did not find the table sequence_order_1,

Who can help me to solve this problem
Thank you

Itm Song

Answer (score 0):

Please try reindex once since store id with order sequence may be wrong. 
Still issue persist, do the following steps, 
found the table name as **sales_sequence_meta** in your database and remove the record of 
[image]

entity_type as order and store_id as 1 and sequence_table as sequence_order_1

After that , do the reindex once and check it out. 
Hope it works for you or points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, i found the original version of my web in another server's db contains the table sequence_order_0, sequence_order_1 and all other related table.

So the root cause of this issue was due to, when i backuped the db  and restored it in my new server, these 6 more tables was lost. since no table, so exception occurred

Thank you for everyone's comments and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **n98-magerun2** (https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2)

```
n98-magerun2.phar sales:sequence:add [store]
```

example

```
n98-magerun2.phar sales:sequence:remove 1
n98-magerun2.phar sales:sequence:add 1
```

see https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2/pull/1177

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the sequence tables missing for the store.

**var/log/exception.log**

> Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view
> not found: 1146 Table 'xxx.sequence_order_3' doesn't exist, query was:
> INSERT INTO `sequence_order_3` () VALUES () in
> /app/xxx/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:109

`n98-magerun2.phar sales:sequence:add [store_id]` didn't work for me.

So, I had to manually create the missing sequence tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `sequence_order_3` (`sequence_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`));
CREATE TABLE `sequence_invoice_3` (`sequence_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`));
CREATE TABLE `sequence_creditmemo_3` (`sequence_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`));
CREATE TABLE `sequence_shipment_3` (`sequence_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`));
CREATE TABLE `sequence_rma_item_3` (`sequence_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`sequence_value`));
```

And, that fixed the issue for me.